# mule asynchronous tls/ssl inbound endpoint

Tags: ssl, asynchronous, mule, polling

I'm working on a project where one of the requirements is to connect to a server using ssl/tls and subscribe to messages. I have setup a tls outbound-endpoint and can connect to the server. I have a spring bean that performs custom handshaking and part of that is subscribing to content from the server. Once subscribed I should receive messages asynchronously without having to poll for them. Is there a way to do this in Mule 3.3? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe you are saying that you need to pull message from HTTPS endpoint. You have to poll for the messages. I can't imagine how the messages can be consumed unless you are polling for those. The subscription just means that the messages will be available for consumption. You still need to consume it somehow. Please put a little more explanation to describe your scenario.

Comment: Actually its over a secure tcp connection. In order to connect as a client to a server is by setting up a tcp outbound endpoint. The problem with that is that its either one-way or synchronous (one for one). Mule has a polling connector for tcp but I don't think there's one for secure tcp. I could be wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used a quartz inbound endpoint and setup an endpoint polling job and polled my endpoint. See the config below:

```
<flow name="QuartzPollingFlow">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint repeatCount="-1" repeatInterval="1000" jobName="myPoller">
        <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
            <quartz:job-endpoint timeout="300" ref="SecureTcpEndpoint"/>
        </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <flow-ref name="ProcessingFlow"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have a specific use case in which you can't use HTTPS. Mule does provide support for TCP connection, but I couldn't find the option to make the the secure TCP connection (which I beleive will be over SSL).

You can always write your custom endpoint connector code in a java component and call that java component using Quartz (for polling)

```
<flow name="polling-flow" doc:name="polling-flow">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="polling"
        repeatInterval="5000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:event-generator-job>
            <quartz:payload>call-custom-component-to-poll-secure-tcp</quartz:payload>
        </quartz:event-generator-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <component doc:name="Java" class="com.company.CustomSecureTCPCode"></component>
    <!-- do whatever you want to with the payload received from calling the endpoint -->                
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its not exactly what I was looking for but pointed me in the right direction. See my solution below.